# Plotly Plotting Issues

Tags: python, plotly

I am using the following code to plot a plotly interactive figure:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from plotly import __version__
import cufflinks as cf
import plotly
from plotly.offline import download_plotlyjs,init_notebook_mode,plot,iplot

init_notebook_mode(connected=True)

cf.go_offline()

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(100,4),columns="A B C D".split())
df2 = pd.DataFrame({"Category":['A','B','C'],"Values":[32,43,50]})

plotly.plot(df,"line")

plt.show()
```

and it gives me the following error:

```
{'text/html': '        <script type="text/javascript">\n        window.PlotlyConfig = {MathJaxConfig: \'local\'};\n        if (window.MathJax && window.MathJax.Hub && window.MathJax.Hub.Config) {window.MathJax.Hub.Config({SVG: {font: "STIX-Web"}});}\n        if (typeof require !== \'undefined\') {\n        require.undef("plotly");\n        requirejs.config({\n            paths: {\n                \'plotly\': [\'https://cdn.plot.ly/plotly-2.12.1.min\']\n            }\n        });\n        require([\'plotly\'], function(Plotly) {\n            window._Plotly = Plotly;\n        });\n        }\n        </script>\n        '}
```

Let me know what I should do so I can plot plotly graphs error free!

Comment: Try this: `import plotly.express as px;px.line(df2, x='Category', y='Values')` or `px.line(df, y=['A','B','C','D'])`

Comment: it's sadly giving me the same exact error as before. Do you still call `plt.show()` for plotly graphs?

Comment: It worked for me after commenting `plt.show()`. This is on jupyter notebook using python 3.8.8 and plotly 5.8.0

Comment: Maybe it's because I'm using VS Code. I wonder why it wouldn't work with VS Code but would with jupyter notebook.